# How to chain more than 2 jobs using JobChainingJobListener Quartz.net?

Tags: c#, .net, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I want to chain the 3 jobs, but AddJobChainLink() gets only 2 jobKeys as parameter.

```
scheduler = container.GetInstance<IScheduler>();
            scheduler.JobFactory = container.GetInstance<IJobFactory>();    JobKey jobkey1 = new JobKey("job1", "group1");
            JobKey jobkey2 = new JobKey("job2", "group2");
            JobKey jobkey3 = new JobKey("job3", "group3");

            var job1 = JobBuilder.Create<Type1>().WithIdentity("job1", "group1").Build();
            var job2 = JobBuilder.Create<Type2>().WithIdentity("job2", "group2").Build();
            var job3 = JobBuilder.Create<Type3>().WithIdentity("job3", "group3").Build();

            ITrigger trigger1 = TriggerBuilder.Create().WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1").StartNow().Build();

            JobChainingJobListener chain = new JobChainingJobListener("testChain");
            chain.AddJobChainLink(jobkey1, jobkey2);
            scheduler.ScheduleJob(job1, trigger1);
            scheduler.AddJob(job2, true);
            scheduler.AddJob(job3, true);

            scheduler.ListenerManager.AddJobListener(chain, GroupMatcher<JobKey>.AnyGroup());

            scheduler.Start();
```

Comment: Have you tried to chain `jobkey1` -> `jobkey2` and `jobkey2` -> `jobkey3`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
JobChainingJobListener chain = new JobChainingJobListener("testChain");
chain.AddJobChainLink(jobkey1, jobkey2);
chain.AddJobChainLink(jobkey2, jobkey3);
```

`JobChainingJobListener` helps you create a chain of execution for your jobs in a specific order you desire. You just need to chain each job with another in specific order.

Comment: I think this will run the job number 2 twice. what do you think?

Comment: @Beginner no, it won't.

Comment: It would appear that the child jobs must be set as durable, otherwise they're never triggered again after the initial trigger.

Comment: How will this behave when jobs are submitted in bulk?